# Is it possible to show all found results together in the LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice, search, find, microsoft-word

In MS Word you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search a typographical object (sign(s), letter(s), word(s)). A full list of the results is displayed in the left pane (search-engine style: enumerated, with context, and location [page]), so you can have the full picture of a given search in your document without the need to flip pages. Is this possible to display a similar list of the results in the Libre Office Writer? Being forced to look for the highlighted results through pages again is very unhandy in the large documents.

I have LibreOffice *v.: 5.3.7.2, build ID: 1:5.3.7~rc2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1~lo0* 
I have not found the answer in the [LibreOffice's wiki](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Find_and_Replace#Find).

Comment: Try asking at http://ask.libreoffice.org as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [AltSearch](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/alternative-dialog-find-replace-for-writer), it is possible to redirect search results to another Writer window.  The following replacement expression lists item and page number found, as well as the text.

```
\i page \I:  &\n\R
```

Be sure to check the *Regular expressions* box for this to work.

For example, searching for `.*a.*` in my test document produced four search results.

```
1 page 1:  bbabb 
2 page 2:  ccacc 
3 page 2:  ddadd 
4 page 3:  eeaee
```

Then consider lining up the two windows side by side to conveniently browse results.

**EDIT**:

To open the AltSearch dialog, go to *Edit -> Alt. Find & Replace...*

Comment: I installed it in the VMware on Ubuntu 16.04 'xenial'. I have to learn this plug-in. For now, I cannot find how to call it. I need sth simple as I am low on time. It would have been helpful, though, if you extended your answer into small _how-to_, giving more robust explanation.

Comment: @Christianus: See edited answer.

Comment: It works as a stopgap. Could you explain the semantics of `\i page \I:  &\n\R`, please?

Comment: In the dialog, click on `?` to see explanations of the options.  Look under *Replacing*.

Comment: Can we translate a command into `batch`, to create a shortcut in a _Batch manager_? What should be between `[Find]` and `[Replace]` to make batch prompt an input window to type what I would like to be searched? `; separator \n [Name] All results \n [Find] \n [Replace] \i page \I:  &\n\R \n [Parameters]   MsgOff  Regular \n [Command] ReplaceAll \n ; separator` I tried `set /p input="input"` before and `echo %input%` between, in vain.

Comment: I don't see any such command in the documentation, but you could post a new question on ask.libreoffice.org to see if anyone else knows of a way.